# Can I do a python request using google vpn extension?

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I just want to get my location using python.requests by retrieving the content of this website 'http://ipinfo.io/json'.

I planned to get the website content using google vpn extension (hola vpn) by using coockies. BUT I can't get the content of this website while using google vpn extension due to unknown reason

code:

```
import requests
import browser_cookie3

cookies = browser_cookie3.chrome(cookie_file="C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1\\Network\\Cookies")
response = requests.get('http://ipinfo.io/json', cookies=cookies)
print(response.content)
```

Note: I can do it by using selenium but I want another way to do it